# External JS in React App - Rendering issue

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react an trying to add external JS in react App.
However no approach is working for me as JS does not work at all.

Below is my code. What is wrong with the code?

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import React, { Component }  from 'react';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import ScriptTag from 'react-script-tag';
import {Helmet} from "react-helmet";

function App() {
  return ( 
  <div className='App'>
    <h1>This is external javascript - Helmet</h1>
    <Helmet>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" 
    type="text/javascript" />
    </Helmet>
    
    <h1>This is external javascript - ScriptTag</h1>
      <ScriptTag isHydrating={true} type="text/javascript" 
      src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" />
    
  </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use jquery cdn directly inside the react js project. Rather you can go with the below plugin to use jquery inside your react js project,

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-jquery-plugin

Just install it with below code,

```
npm install --save react-jquery-plugin
```

Comment: It is not related to jquery only. I want to know how ANY javascript can be loaded/used in react

Comment: It depends on the package you are using. Few packages can be added as cdn and will directly work in react js project. But it is not suggestable to use cdn directly in react js project. Instead we should go with npm packages.